# Tax Calculation for selected products

Tags: magento-1.9, tax-class

Is it possible to setup tax for selected products in USA and all products in Canada ? If I set tax class to all products for canada, it also apply the same for USA.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.First you need to create new **Product Tax Clas**s.

2.Then **2** separate **Tax Rates** - One for USA & one for CANADA

[image]

3.Than Create **Tax Rule** - Assign **Product Tax Class** & **Tax Rates** to Tax Rule.

[image]

Feel free to check below links

https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/how-create-tax-rule-magento

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/tax/tax-rules.html

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/magento/magento_setup_taxes.htm

http://www.harapartners.com/blog/setting-tax-classes-magento-tax-setup/

Comment: I am not sure if you understand my question  e.g if I have 2 product A,B and C and i want tax to be applied for all 3 product for Canata , i need to set product tax class to be set as Taxable Goods,  but I do not need tax for US for Product A, how can i set not to calculate tax because I have selected product class Taxable goods which is reuquire for canada, so eventually it will calculate tax for US as well. which i do not want for all product and require only for selected product

Comment: @Pravin dont use taxable goods, create 2 different `product tax class` , example : `usa` & `usacan` , than create 2 different tax rule : in `taxrule1` assign both `product tax class` `usa` & `usacan` and in `taxrule2` assign only `usa` . than for product  B & C select tax class : `usacan` and for product A , select tax class A..... before all these, please go through the links and learn about taxes.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento, can we set the custom tax_amount for quote item? here is my question,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart

Comment: @jafarpinjar Sorry, no idea  about magento2, feel free to open bounty for that question after 48 hours.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento, yes sure..

Comment: @BabyinMagento, I have enabled the bounty for my question, please have a look once.

Comment: @jafarpinjar i didt saw you enabled bounty for that question....

Comment: @BabyinMagento, that was enabled for more than one week, automatically removed now

Comment: @jafarpinjar you can open one more for 100 points.... hope you will get answer this time......